# Refresh a jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I can't seem to get my table to refresh. I created a refresh button that calls `jTable1.repaint();`

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)        
// Reader Refresh
        jTable1.repaint();
    }
```

I also tried just recalling the `RegistryValues` again in the button like `RegistryValues.arp(null);`

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)        
// Reader Refresh
        RegistryValues.arp(null);
    }
```

Also tried combining the registryvalues and repaint in the button.

Below is the code for my `jTable`. The `RegistryValues` are from another class that uses JNA to read the registry if that matters.

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"Protected Mode at Startup", RegistryValues.arp(null)},
                {"Display PDF in browser", RegistryValues.arb(null)},
                {"EULA Accepted?", RegistryValues.are(null)},
                {null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Software", "Status"
            }
        ));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither

```
jTable1.repaint();
```

or

```
RegistryValues.arp(null);
```

will actually refresh the table with new values. For this you need to either update the current table model or set a new model but in your ActionListener.

As you're using [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), which is mutable, you could create an update helper method for the model.

Something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.setValueAt(RegistryValues.arp(null), 0, 1);
// set more row data, etc.
```

**Note:** You could save the model as a class member variable and eliminate the need for casting.

Comment: @jerhynsoen: You define a DefaultTableModel in your question.  Make the default table model its own class with update capability.

Comment: @Gilbert, Its own class or its own method?

Comment: @jerhynsoen: Extend DefaultTableModel into a MyTableModel class and add update capability.  Sorry that I wasn't clearer the first time.

Comment: -1 for the second part: never-ever fire any events on behalf of the model (that's its own responsibility). Instead, fix the model to fire the events as needed.